# Configuring a custom dns and proxy setup

Tags: dns, proxy, https, squid, haproxy

I have a smart-dns setup,
Using dnsmasq as the dns server, which always resolves to my server ip address, for a given list of domains.

I want a configure either a webserver or proxy program  to listen on port 80 and 443 on my server . Which then forwards all the web requests, to an external proxy server (squid) as proxy requests.

Would it be possible to do this, using programs like (nginx, harproxy, squid..etc), for both http and https traffic, without ssl termination.

So far, none of the configs i have tested worked,
Haproxy config.

```
frontend https_front
bind *:443
mode tcp
default_backend squid_backend_https

backend squid_backend_https
mode tcp
server squid_proxy 111.22.32.11:3323
```

Nginx config,

```
stream {
upstream ssl_backend {
    server  111.22.32.11:3323;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    proxy_protocol on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    proxy_pass ssl_backend;

 proxy_ssl_protocols TLSV1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
 proxy_ssl_ciphers 'HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5';
    proxy_ssl on;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    #proxy_next_upstream on;
   proxy_ssl_verify off;
}
}
```

I presume, that the backend program listening on 80 and 443, Should effectively, forward the http/https web request, as a proxy request to the external proxy server (squid).

Any help, on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks